# CardView not displaying when run on device that has api 21 beelow

Tags: java, android, firebase

I need help. Why is it CardView isn't displaying on my device . But works with API 22- UP.  already added google mawen inside my gradle file. And already search for possible alternatives, still it didn't run. What could be the reason for this? or Do you have suggeestions with the problem i've encountered?. Thank you in advance!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CFD8DC"
    tools:context="com.example.ninjathegreat.ligaocitysolidwastemanagementv20.MainActivity">


    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="10"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <include
            layout="@layout/app_bar"
            android:id="@+id/app_bar"
            />


        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/relativeID"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eswm"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/eswm"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textSize="34sp" />

        <GridLayout
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:id="@+id/mainGrid"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="412dp"
            android:layout_weight="8"
            android:alignmentMode="alignMargins"
            android:columnCount="2"
            android:columnOrderPreserved="false"
            android:padding="14dp"
            android:rowCount="3">

            <!-- Row 1 -->

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">


                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/gps"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/gps"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#020202"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/recycle"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/educational_guide"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#020202"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/calendar_2"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/waste_schedule"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#020202"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                app:cardElevation="8dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                    android:layout_margin="16dp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:drawableTop="@drawable/info"
                        android:padding="5dp"
                        android:text="@string/information_1"
                        android:textAlignment="center"
                        android:textColor="#020202"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />


                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
        </GridLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: show error log please.

Comment: if possible show the screenshot on below 21 api and on above 21 so that we can sort out the differences.

Comment: Got it already! Should be<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout> instead of
<GridLayout>,

Comment: sounds good you can answer to your own question for others help.

Answer (score 0):

try   `app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"` propert

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/card_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:elevation="2dp">
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```